# I've done everything from the vue 2.x version to the webpack settings, but I can't import the geojson file

Tags: javascript, webpack, vuejs2, openlayers, geojson

I am trying to add a layer with geojson using openlayers.

However, in the vue2.x version, the geojson file cannot be imported, so the layer cannot be added.

My webpack config right now is(vue.config.js):

`

```
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    lineOnSave: false,

    devServer: {
        proxy: 'http://localhost:8080'
    },

configureWebpack: {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.geojson$/,
                loader: 'json-loader'
            }
        ],
        resolve: {
            extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".jsx", 'json', 'geojson'],
          },
        plugins : [
            new VueLoaderPlugin(),
        ],
    }
}

}
```

`

The code for mainMap.vue in the vue file is:

`

```
import koreaPath from '../assets/geojsonFile/korean.geojson'
mounted(){

    this.createKoreaMap()
}


data() {
    return{
        olmap: undefined,
        
    }
},

methods: {
    createKoreaMap() {

        this.olmap = new OlMap({
            target: this.$refs.map,
            layers: [
                new OlLayerTile({
                    source: new OSM({
                        url: 'https://xdworld.vworld.kr/2d/midnight/service/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
                    })
                })
            ],
            view: new OlView({
                center: fromLonLat([126.978275264, 37.566642192]), // 경기도 성남
                zoom: 10
            })
        })
}
```

`

Finally, when I build with npm run serve, the error is:

```
@ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-40.use[0]!./node_modules/@vue/vue-loader-v15/lib/index.js??vue-loader-options!./src/components/mainMap.vue?vue&type=script&las!./src/components/mainMap.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& 14:0-61
@ ./src/components/mainMap.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& 1:0-201 1:217-220 1:222-420 1:222-420
@ ./src/components/mainMap.vue 2:0-59 3:0-54 3:0-54 10:2-8
@ ./src/components/mainMap.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& 1:0-201 1:217-220 1:222-420 1:222-420                                         s!./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& 1:0-47 9
@ ./src/components/mainMap.vue 2:0-59 3:0-54 3:0-54 10:2-8
@ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-40.use[0]!./node_modules/@vue/vue-loader-v15/lib/index.js??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& 1:0-47 9:4-11
@ ./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& 1:0-191 1:207-210 1:212-400 1:212-400
@ ./src/App.vue 2:0-55 3:0-50 3:0-50 10:2-8
@ ./src/main.js 2:0-28 7:17-20


webpack compiled with 1 error
```

I've tried different ways but I'm suffering for two days. What should I do??

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to import a JSON file in Vue:

```js
import jsonFile from '@/assets/geojsonFile/korean.geojson'
```

Here is an example of webpack(v5) config:

```js
module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.vue$/, loader: "vue-loader" },
      // JavaScript: Use Babel to transpile JavaScript files
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
            plugins: ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"],
          },
        },
      },

      // Images: Copy image files to build folder
      { test: /\.(?:ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg)$/i, type: "asset/resource" },

      // Fonts and SVGs: Inline files
      { test: /\.(woff(2)?|eot|ttf|otf|svg|)$/, type: "asset/inline" },
    ],
  },

  resolve: {
    modules: ["paths/to/src", "node_modules"],
    extensions: [".js", ".ts", ".json"],
    alias: {
      "@": "paths/to/src",
      assets: "paths/to/static",
    },
  },
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for answer.

I tried the way you told me, but it doesn't work :(

Comment: try to change file to `korean.geo.json`, and make sure the file path is right @Seung12

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).